# Для кого пишется документация?

Tags: документация

Предположим команда разрабатывает не программу которую можно взять и использовать, а библиотеку которая предназначена для использования другими программистами. Так вот: документация кода пишется для людей которые будут использовать библиотеку или для команды её разрабатывающей?

Comment: Для всех сразу, например?

Comment: @andreymal остаётся вопрос как в комментарии к ответу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для тех, кто будет использовать ваш продукт документация по его применению, установке и т.д. обязательно нужна. В противном случае ваше творение просто никто (может кроме нескольких нердов) не будет даже пробовать.

Внутренняя документация (в т.ч. описывающая процесс сборки) крайне желательна, но часто на нее не хватает времени и вся команда отделывается отговорками о самодокоментируемом коде.

Comment: Ох, как часто я слышу эти отговорки. :)

Answer (score 2):

Есть многомудрый ГОСТ 19.*** о документации на программное обеспечение.
В этом ГОСТе сказано какая документация и в каком виде должна быть.

Если коротко:

1. Для пользователей пишется описание применения - то есть описание интерфейса (то есть перечень вызовов) программы и/или библиотеки.
2. Для разработчиков пишется описание программы - это описание внутренней структуры программы с учетом текста на языке, на котором программа написана.

Answer (score 1):

Часто пишут документацию чтобы легко понять что библиотека (функции или методы классов) получает на вход и что отдает на выходе. Если библиотека публичная то пишется для всех, а если приватная то для команды.

Comment: А если нужно описать как работает метод, т.е. подробно чтобы был понятен код - это писать в документацию или нет? А приватные переменные, нужные только для внутреннего использования?

Comment: @wcobalt советую почитать книгу "Стив Макконнелл: Совершенный код", там есть главы про разные best practices.